# CSS transform transition - using ´px´ more smooth/performant than 'percentage'

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I've recently been looking into improving the animations on my website - more specifically of the navigation dropdown on mobile devices.

In this connection I stumbled upon the following case, which I'm hoping to get some more in-depth knowledge about.

The case is that when transitioning/animating `transform: translate3d()` it seems that the browser requires more calculations when it's applied using `%` rather than `px`. E.g. in my tests it seems that transitioning from `transform: translate3d(0, 500px, 0)` to `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` requires less computations and runs smoother than transitioning from `transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0)`.

**Update:** Upon testing further I've found that using `100vh`/`100vw` bypasses/mitigates the issue of using percentages. This can be usefyk in cases where the element has a known percentage width of the window or is full-width, and thereby improve the performance. Actually it seems that using this value behaves as if it was assigned with `px` value in Chrome.

Here is a couple of pictures of the timeline from each animation. The timelines are obtained using Google Dev tools under "Performance". To better show the difference the performance has been limited in Chrome Dev Tools to "low-end mobile" (6x CPU slowdown).

**Transform using percent:**

[image: Transform performance using percent (%)]

**Transform using pixel (px):**

[image: Transform performance using pixel (px)]

As can be seen from the images it seems that alot more rendering and painting is going on when using `%` rather than `px` to determine the transformation. It makes great sense that the browser has to calculate the percentage values for each frame (I guess?), but I'm surprised that it takes that much more, compared to using a pixel value.

**Also** please note that the framerates in the picture showing the timeline of percentage never reaches ~60 fps, but is rather averaging around 40 fps.

Below is snippets to replicate the case. There's one using percent and one using px.

```js
$(document).on("click", function(){
$(".bb").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.aa{
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;

}
.bb{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  background:none;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  transform:translateZ(0);
  overflow:hidden;
    pointer-events:none;
}
.cc{
  height:100%;
    transform:translate3d(0,500px,0);
    width:100%;
      transition:transform .5s ease-in;
      background:red;
}
.bb.active .cc{
  transform:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the document to start animation<p>
<div class="bb">
<div class="cc">
<ul>
<li>Point one</li>
<li>Point two</li>
<li>Point three</li>
<li>Point four</li>
<li>Point five</li>
<li>Point six</li>
<li>Point seven</li>
</ul><ul>
<li>Point one</li>
<li>Point two</li>
<li>Point three</li>
<li>Point four</li>
<li>Point five</li>
<li>Point six</li>
<li>Point seven</li>
</ul>

</div>

</div>
```

```js
$(document).on("click", function(){
$(".bb").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.aa{
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;

}
.bb{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  background:none;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  transform:translateZ(0);
  overflow:hidden;
    pointer-events:none;
}
.cc{
  height:100%;
    transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);
    width:100%;
      transition:transform .5s ease-in;
      background:red;
}
.bb.active .cc{
  transform:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the document to start animation<p>
<div class="bb">
<div class="cc">
<ul>
<li>Point one</li>
<li>Point two</li>
<li>Point three</li>
<li>Point four</li>
<li>Point five</li>
<li>Point six</li>
<li>Point seven</li>
</ul><ul>
<li>Point one</li>
<li>Point two</li>
<li>Point three</li>
<li>Point four</li>
<li>Point five</li>
<li>Point six</li>
<li>Point seven</li>
</ul>

</div>

</div>
```

To solve this "issue" in which using percentages in `transform` possibly causes worsened animation performance, I've made the following suggestion, which might improve the performance. However, I'm interested in hearing other opinions as I'm not quite sure whether this should be necessary and why(?).

What I'm doing is basically just using jQuery to apply the `transform` value in pixels rather than percentage. For production cases this will naturally require to be updated on window resizes.

The resulting timeline for this approach is:

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var bbWidth = $("#bb .cc").css('transform').split(',')[5].slice(0,-1);

$("#bb .cc").css("transform", "translate3d(0," + bbWidth + "px,0");
$(document).on("click", function(){
$("#bb").toggleClass("active");
});
});
```

```css
.aa{
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;

}
#bb{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  background:none;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  transform:translateZ(0);
  overflow:hidden;
}
.cc{
  height:100%;
    transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);
    width:100%;
      transition:transform .5s ease-in;
      background:red;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
}
#bb.active .cc{
  transform:none!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bb">
<div class="cc">
<ul>
<li>Point one</li>
<li>Point two</li>
<li>Point three</li>
<li>Point four</li>
<li>Point five</li>
<li>Point six</li>
<li>Point seven</li>
</ul><ul>
<li>Point one</li>
<li>Point two</li>
<li>Point three</li>
<li>Point four</li>
<li>Point five</li>
<li>Point six</li>
<li>Point seven</li>
</ul>

</div>

</div>
```

**Question:**

- Is it correct that I'm experiencing this behaviour (assigning value in `px` performs better than `%`) and if so, why is this happening? As mentioned earlier it kinda makes sense to me that it should, but I'm really lacking some technological/in-depth explanation.
- Is there a better way to bypass this issue than my suggestion? Using `transform: translate()` to e.g. hide navigations off-screen is very circumstantial if you "can't" use `%` and if you want smooth animations at the same time.

Comment: not sure at 100% but I guess the use of % values make the browser to calculate these values very often as it may change during the animation since it's a relative value unlike the px one. A good test case is to make the animation slower and during it resize your browser and see the performance of both.

Comment: Have you tried `transform: translate3d(0, calc(100%), 0);` I can't currently test this, but maybe it tricks the browser into using px units?!

Comment: @yoshi as a matter of fact I have, as I believe the same thought as yours crossed my mind (that `calc ()` would turn it into a px value in the browser), sadly with the same result as using `%`. Temani, that's my thought as well and a good idea

Comment: Have you tried adding a *will-change: transform* rule ?

Comment: @vals yes, and that yields the same result as the original case using `%`. This is also expected I guess, as the element is already "offloaded" to the GPU by using `translate3d()`

Answer (score 2):

> Is it correct that I'm experiencing this behaviour (assigning value in px performs better than %) and if so, why is this happening? As mentioned earlier it kinda makes sense to me that it should, but I'm really lacking some technological/in-depth explanation.

It's correct indeed. Pixels are absolute values (i.e. are not dependent on anything and represented ‘as is’). Percentages are relative values, which means they have to depend on some other value in order to produce result. So every time you assign a percentage value it has to get it's relative value to perform a calculation.
When doing a translation with pixels you only have to change the translation values, but with percentages you have to get element's dimensions first and then apply the translation. And that has to be done for every animation frame.

To mitigate this issue you have to recalculate element's dimensions only once before the animation. Then use `!important` to override what's set in the style attribute. The code in the snippet does exactly that.

Also notice that I've added a `resize` listener. That's required if the window gets resized, so your element becomes hidden.

```js
$(function(){
var $el = $("#bb");
$(document).on("click", function(){
  var height = $el.outerHeight();
  $el
    .css('transform', 'translateY(' + height + 'px)')
    .toggleClass("active");
});
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  $el.removeClass('active').removeAttr('style');
});
});
```

```css
#bb{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  background-color: red;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform .5s ease-in;
}
#bb.active
{
  transform: translateY(0px) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bb">
<div class="cc">
<ul>
<li>Point one</li>
<li>Point two</li>
<li>Point three</li>
<li>Point four</li>
<li>Point five</li>
<li>Point six</li>
<li>Point seven</li>
</ul><ul>
<li>Point one</li>
<li>Point two</li>
<li>Point three</li>
<li>Point four</li>
<li>Point five</li>
<li>Point six</li>
<li>Point seven</li>
</ul>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To further expand on the answer given by CyperAP and the suggestions made in my original question I've also found that using CSS3 `vw` and `vh` values bypasses the issue that using `%` cause.

This use-case is especially useful in situations in which the element-to-be-transitioned has been given a height/width based on the windows' size - e.g. if the element is full-width (`100%`/`100vw`).

Based on the example from the original question and instead using `transform: translate3d(0, 100vh, 0)` yields the following timeline result (again, in Chrome with performance limited to "Low end mobile"):

[image]

Snippet can be seen here:

```js
$(document).on("click", function(){
$(".bb").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.aa{
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;

}
.bb{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  background:none;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  transform:translateZ(0);
  overflow:hidden;
    pointer-events:none;
}
.cc{
  height:100%;
    transform:translate3d(0,100vh,0);
    width:100%;
      transition:transform .5s ease-in;
      background:red;
}
.bb.active .cc{
  transform:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the document to start animation<p>
<div class="bb">
<div class="cc">
<ul>
<li>Point one</li>
<li>Point two</li>
<li>Point three</li>
<li>Point four</li>
<li>Point five</li>
<li>Point six</li>
<li>Point seven</li>
</ul><ul>
<li>Point one</li>
<li>Point two</li>
<li>Point three</li>
<li>Point four</li>
<li>Point five</li>
<li>Point six</li>
<li>Point seven</li>
</ul>

</div>

</div>
```