# How to remove blur effect after scale transition?

Tags: css

Have a box with some text inside. When I hover it, I want to scale / zoom it bigger with an animation. When the animation ends, the blurred effect is removed from the container. Is there anyway to remove the blur effect after the transition ?

**The Code (http://codepen.io/ptongalex/pen/dNZdmV):**

```css
.box {
  border: solid red 2px;
  width: 100px;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  left: 50%;
  top:200px;
}
.box:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: scale(3);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see any blur effect on it...

Comment: @Omnitored yes you can, look at the text when it's scaled

Comment: You do not use any blur. Filter: blur() takes a px value. The larger value the bigger blur. You have specified 0

Comment: @Viktor and still have blur effect :)

Comment: Ok, then it has nothing to do with the fact that you specified filter: blur(). Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411361/webkit-based-blurry-distorted-text-post-animation-via-translate3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to start you box as big and then have it scaled down to your desired size. When you then hover the box you scale it up to 1. This way you prevent the box and its content from being pixelated/blurry when scaling:

```css
.box {
  border: solid red 6px;
  width: 300px;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 54px;
  transform: scale(0.33);
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It still looks blurry to me during animation.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
filter: none; 
-webkit-filter: blur(0); 
-moz-filter: blur(0); 
-ms-filter: blur(0);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='0');
```

But in some cases the element will be blurred during animation if you use transition.