# How to fix the position of the div tag at center of the page. using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

> Possible Duplicate:
>   [how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page)

I need to show this Div tag allways center of the page. but its not showing now its shwoing right hand side corner and center of the page some times. Allways I need to show this page at center.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have any height/width/top/left/bottom/right arguments to specify actual position

Comment: If you are using Jquery go ahead use Jquery UI that could resolve your issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align a <div> to the middle (horizontally/width) of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-horizontally-width-of-the-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a width to your div and add the margin css property shown below

```
 <div style="width:500px; margin:0 auto;">
     Your content
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set width to 50%, then left position to 25% -> that way, your div will always be centered, no matter if you resize parent object.

```
#header {   
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
}

<div id='test' class='#header'>My content goes here</div>
```