# Align a div horizontal to center of the page

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have this piece of html code:

```
<div id="main" style=" margin:0 auto; ">
    <div style="float: left">
        <a style="display: block" href="#"><img src="test.gif"></a>
        <a style="display: block" href="#"><img src="test.gif"></a>
        <a style="display: block" href="#"><img src="test.gif"></a>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left">
        <a style="display: block;" href="#"><img src="ursus.gif"></a>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left">
        <a style="display: block" href="#"><img src="test.gif"></a>
        <a style="display: block" href="#"><img src="test.gif"></a>
        <a style="display: block" href="#"><img src="test.gif"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want the #main div to be align in the center of the page. How cand I do this? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must set a `width` for the div:

```
<div id="main" style="margin:0 auto; width:700px;">
```

I would also strongly suggest that you don't use inline css. Add something like this in a external stylesheet instead:

```
#main {
   margin:0 auto;
   width:700px;
}
#main a {
   display:block;
}
#main > div {
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: is there way do do this without setting the width? I want my div to be centered regardless it's width.

Comment: @zuzuleinen, only if you're using JavaScript to center it. Otherwise, you've gotta designate a width.

Comment: I think you could get away with setting a `max-with` for your div.

Answer (score 2):

```
<body>
<div id="main" style=" margin:0 auto; width: 960px;">
    <div style="float: left">
        <a style="display: block" href="#"><img src="test.gif"></a>
        <a style="display: block" href="#"><img src="test.gif"></a>
        <a style="display: block" href="#"><img src="test.gif"></a>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left">
        <a style="display: block;" href="#"><img src="ursus.gif"></a>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left">
        <a style="display: block" href="#"><img src="test.gif"></a>
        <a style="display: block" href="#"><img src="test.gif"></a>
        <a style="display: block" href="#"><img src="test.gif"></a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned in a comment to Krister Andersson you want the `div` to center no matter the width. But you have to give some kind of width info. If you want the `div` to be flexible width but centered then you need to set specific ***equal*** margins:

```
#main {
    margin: 0 50px; /* or whatever px, em, or % you want */
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jBYZq/.

The point is, you have to either set the width of the element and use `margin: 0 auto` or set the margins of the element equal. But something has to be set to get it centered.