# How to align a div in center of page

Tags: css, html, center, alignment

I'm making a mobile website & I'm stuck in a problem. I have a main `div` and inside it there are three `div`'s. Earlier I wanted it left aligned but now I want to align these three `div`'s to the center of the page. i.e. if the screen of the device is wide it should come to the center, right now it's left aligned.

I tried many ways but not able to get it. Here is the code & css
I know  the sizes should be in em's & not pixels; I'll fix that soon.

```
<div class="main-buttons">
<div class="box1"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div class="box2"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div class="box3"><a href="#"></a></div>
</div><!-- MAIN BUTTONS ENDS HERE -->


.main-buttons{ height:42px; padding:5px 10px 5px 10px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-bottom:dotted 1px #7c7c7c;}

.box1 a { background-image:url(images/box1.jpg); height:42px; margin-right:6px; width:65px; }
.box2 a { background-image:url(images/box2.jpg); height:42px; margin-right:6px; width:65px; }
.box3 a { background-image:url(images/box2.jpg); height:42px; width:65px; }
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in CSS by setting the margin property.

For the parent div use the following css and it should work fine

```
.main-contents
{
    margin: 10px auto; 
    height:42px; 
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px; 
    background-color:#FFFFFF; border-bottom:dotted 1px #7c7c7c;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3
{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, bt its not working. sorry if my question is confusing i want it to be horizontally center aligned.

Comment: I am not sure how can this not work.... in your CSS for `.main-buttons` , add the margin property I specified in answer and it should work the way you want....

Comment: I don't know whats wrong i tried ur method but still its not working fine, may be b'coz i have * { margin:0; padding:0; } in my CSS, i tried removing it for testing but still its not coming in center.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution I just had to add one more line of css & had to put my sub div's inside this div. As i do not want to add width to my main parent div, i added one more div & gave `{margin:0 auto;}` to it. I dont know if this method is right but it solved my problem.

```
<div class="main-buttons">
<div class="sub-buttons">
<div class="box1"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div class="box2"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div class="box3"><a href="#"></a></div>
</div><!-- SUB DIV ENDS HERE -->
</div><!-- MAIN BUTTONS ENDS HERE -->
```

CSS:

```
.main-buttons{ height:42px; padding:5px 10px 5px 10px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-bottom:dotted 1px #7c7c7c;}
.sub-buttons{ width:202px; height:42px; margin:0 auto;}

.box1 a { background-image:url(images/box1.jpg); height:42px; margin-right:6px; width:65px; }
.box2 a { background-image:url(images/box2.jpg); height:42px; margin-right:6px; width:65px; }
.box3 a { background-image:url(images/box2.jpg); height:42px; width:65px; }
```