# How to align a <div> to center of the page

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to align a <div> to the middle of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page)

I have a div tag with hight set to 800px, I want that when the browser width is greater than 600px it shouldn't stretch the div but it should bring it to the middle of the page

How can I achieve this?

can I use the following code?

    
        centered content

Comment: you can try margin: auto, but be advised this wont work well in all browsers esp. IE

Comment: Off-topic, but I could not help sharing this: https://youtu.be/91TCgj_pQ98?t=3m

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:

with margin set to auto

```
<html>
<head><title>Your Title</title></head>
<body>
<div style="width:600px; margin:auto; border:1px solid red">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Long answer:

You might want to set an id for that div, and give appropriate css selector with the rules rather than using inline style like that.

Also, for that to work correctly in ie 6 and 7, you need to give the doctype declaration, otherwise it won't work because ie will work in quirks mode 
http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/quirksmode.html

So the complete answer should look like

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
       <title>Your Title</title>
       <style>#container { width:600px; margin:auto; border:1px solid red }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="container">
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can I use the following code?    <body>
    <div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
        centered content
    </div>
</body>

Comment: Yes you can, 0 auto just means margin 0 for top and bottom, auto for left and right.

Answer (score 0):

put in the css the following properites :

```
max-width:600px;
position:relative;
margin:auto;
```

one thing I am not clear is do you want the div to take the width of the browser if the browser width is less than 600px?

Comment: position is relative by default

Comment: actually position is parent's position by default. We dont know exactly where the div is present

Comment: can I use the following code?   <body>
    <div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
        centered content
    </div>
</body>

Comment: I have to disagree, position is `static` by default, that's why you need to explicitly define `position:relative` before `top:` and `left:` takes effect

Comment: @chetan yes you can, since height of the body will take the full height of the div there will be not much difference in the two margin declarations.....
but do you want width to be 800px or 600px?

Comment: @andreas tnx man...I was about to post that
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_position.asp