# Positioning <div> element at center of screen

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to position a `<div>` (or a `<table>`) element at the center of the screen irrespective of screen size. In other words, the space left on 'top' and 'bottom' should be equal and space left on 'right' and 'left' sides should be equal. I would like to accomplish this with only CSS.

I have tried the following but it is not working:

```
 <body>
  <div style="top:0px; border:1px solid red;">
    <table border="1" align="center">
     <tr height="100%">
      <td height="100%" width="100%" valign="middle" align="center">
        We are launching soon!
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
 </body>
```

**Note:**
It is either way fine if the `<div>` element (or `<table>`) scrolls with the website or not. Just want it to be centered when the page loads.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align a <div> to the middle of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page)

Comment: Hi Purmou, the question you mentioned if for positioning at the middle of the page, i.e. left and right side equal space -- not the top and bottom space equal!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's The Best Way of Centering a Div Vertically with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center a div in a div - horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally)

Answer (score 257, accepted):

The easy way, if you have a fixed width and height:

```
#divElement{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}​
```

Please don't use inline styles! Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/.

Comment: For those seeking a dynamic height: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css#6182661

Comment: @woho87 why not use inline styles? for the well known reasons or is there something more that i should know for the specific example?

Comment: @KatrinRaimond it's for the well-known reasons, documented here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css and here http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm.

Comment: But, setting the divElement's top in '%' unit makes the divElement takes up vertical space unless divElement is placed inside a relative element.

Comment: is position:fixed or position:absolute?

Comment: While this was the optimal answer for some time, nowdays CSS is easier  as mentioned in @caps_lock answer

Answer (score 217):

With transforms being more ubiquitously supported these days, you can do this without knowing the width/height of the popup

```
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Easy! JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LgSZV/

**Update:** Check out https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ for a fairly exhaustive guide on CSS centering.  Adding it to this answer as it seems to get a lot of eyeballs.

Comment: If the content in the popup is using `overflow:auto`, scrolling is screwed up in IE9. :(

Comment: Not so ubiquos. IE8 stills [20% of the browser share](http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0) and [don't support it](http://caniuse.com/#search=transforms). So only take this one for IE9+.

Comment: +1 for being the only solution where you don't have to specify height and width or use Javascript.

Comment: @fotanus when developers stop supporting IE 9 < users will either migrate or update their browser.

Comment: @DIegoVieira this is unfortunately not how things work. See [the tragedy of the commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons). So people will continue supporting IE8 because don't want to lose this share, and people will continue using because it works.

Comment: `position:fixed` is useful when you have long page with scroll!

Comment: `translate` will make your font blurry, and it's not easy to fix (solutions don't always work) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109299/css-transform-translate-50-50-makes-texts-blurry

Comment: more details here: https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Answer (score 44):

Set the width and height and you're good.

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

If you want the element dimensions to be flexible (and don't care about legacy browsers), go with **XwipeoutX**'s answer.

Comment: This is the cleanest and simplest answer and is **mobile friendly** too. +1

Comment: It works well, but what is the logic behind how this works?

Answer (score 44):

It will work for any object. Even if you don't know the size:

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Now, is more easy with HTML 5 and CSS 3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body > div {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;

                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>TODO write content</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 19):

Use [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Much simpler and will work regardless of your `div` size:

```css
.center-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="center-screen">
 I'm in the center
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 14):

If you have a fixed `div` just absolute position it at 50% from the top and 50% left and negative margin top and left of half the height and width respectively. Adjust to your needs:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I would do this in CSS:

```
div.centered {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

then in HTML:

```
<div class="centered"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Now you can do this using `grid` layout with fewer lines of code.

```css
.center-this{
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-this">
  <div>
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<table style="height: 100%; left: 0; position: absolute; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div style="text-align: left; display: inline-block;">
    Your Html code Here
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Or this

```
<div style="height: 100%; left: 0; position: absolute; text-align: center; width: 100%; display: table">
 <div style="display: table-row">
  <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">
   <div style="text-align: left; display: inline-block;">
    Your Html code here
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are anyone looking for a solution,

I found this,

Its the best solution i found yet!

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

http://dabblet.com/gist/2872671

Hope you enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Another easy flexible approach to display block at center: using native text alignment with `line-height` and `text-align`.

Solution:

```
.parent {
    line-height: 100vh;        
    text-align: center;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

And html sample:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">My center block</div>
</div>
```

We make `div.parent` fullscreen, and his single child `div.child` align as text with `display: inline-block`.

Advantages:

- flexebility, no absolute values
- support resize
- works fine on mobile

Simple example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k9u6ma8g

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution that doesn't use position absolute:
I see a lot of position absolute answers. I couldn't use position absolute without breaking something else. So for those that couldn't as well, here is what I did:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58622840/6546317 (posted in response to another question).

The solution only focuses on vertically centering because my children elements were already horizontally centered but same could be applied if you couldn't horizontally center them in another way.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
width:360px;
height:360px;
top: 50%; left: 50%;
margin-top: -160px; /* ( ( width / 2 ) * -1 ) */
margin-left: -160px; /* ( ( height / 2 ) * -1 ) */
position:absolute;
```

Comment: This is effectively the same as the accepted answer

Comment: yes, but here i explain the operation of the margin top and left... somebody not know this....

Comment: Then it is effectively the same as the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9862281/1947286)