# How do I align to center div without place on ceter its elements?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to put a div in the center but without place the elements inside the div in the center too. [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/nxp1tb2r/). I want the div itself with border in the center but not its contents (in this case, they should be on right side). How can I do this? I tried with `padding`, `margin` but I can't make it working.

Comment: The div is 100% of the width of it's parent so there's nothing to center. If you don't want the contents centered, remove the `text-align:center`.

Comment: Set a width, then set `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Did you look at [Positioning <div> element at center of screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862167/positioning-div-element-at-center-of-screen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to reset inner elements to 'initial' alignment, saying 'left'.

```
#a {
    border: 2px solid;
    text-align: center;
}
#a * {
    text-align: initial;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nxp1tb2r/5/

Answer (score 2):

a `div` is a block element by default, meaning it'll take up 100% of the width of it's parent. If you want to center-align it, you can do so by specifying a (smaller) fixed width then aligning with `margin: 0 auto;`. This adds an equal amount of margin on each side, making up the rest of the width.

```
#a {
    border: 2px solid;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yj55ttes/

Answer (score 1):

If div A (or B) has a fixed size when you decide to center it, set the css to this:

```
#a {
    width:200px;
    border: 2px solid;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

This will center without using `text-align:center;`

If you don't have a fixed width, set div B to have `text-align:left;`

```
#a {
    border: 2px solid;
    text-align:center;
}
#b {
    text-align:left;
}
```