# Center text in a div and calc() doubts

Tags: html, css

How can I center the text (p) vertically and horizontally inside a div (.item)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper {
            width: auto;
            height: 10em;
            background-color: red;
            position: relative;
        }
        .item {
            width: 4em;
            height: 4em;
            background-color: black;
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
        }
        .item p {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        #top-right {
            right: 0em;
        }
        #center {
            top: calc(50% - 2em);
            right: calc(50% - 2em);
        }
        #bottom-left {
            bottom: 0em;
            left: 0em;
        }
        #bottom-right {
            right: 0em;
            bottom: 0em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header></header>
    <main>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="item" id="top-left"><p>Top Left</p></div>
            <div class="item" id="top-right"><p>Top Right</p></div>
            <div class="item" id="center"><p>Center</p></div>
            <div class="item" id="bottom-left"><p>Bottom Left</p></div>
            <div class="item" id="bottom-right"><p>Bottom Right</p></div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

It's ok to use calc (because I read that this function isn't supported in some browers)? Or there is another way to center the element #center in the div without calc()?

Comment: FYI: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: do you want to center align `#center` in `.wrapper` ??

Comment: You make take a look following link ... may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862167/positioning-div-element-at-center-of-screen

Comment: how about display:table and display:table-cell and then applying vertical-align:middle. I'm skeptical about this

Comment: well i already posted the answer for it..check it http://stackoverflow.com/a/37044205/4119808

Comment: agree with @GauravAggarwal. for reference check this. http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `display: flex`. I have added below properties to your `.item`

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
```

**Updated code snippet:**

```css
.wrapper {
  width: auto;
  height: 10em;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
#top-right {
  right: 0em;
}
#center {
  top: calc(50% - 2em);
  right: calc(50% - 2em);
}
#bottom-left {
  bottom: 0em;
  left: 0em;
}
#bottom-right {
  right: 0em;
  bottom: 0em;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item" id="top-left">
      <p>Top Left</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="top-right">
      <p>Top Right</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="center">
      <p>Center</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="bottom-left">
      <p>Bottom Left</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="bottom-right">
      <p>Bottom Right</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your structure `display:table` and `display:table-cell` would not work because you have used position absolute in `.item`.

Use below css in `#center` which is supported in all broswers.

```
#center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  //top: calc(50% - 2em);
  //right: calc(50% - 2em);
}
```

example : https://jsfiddle.net/vzk5arxe/2/

Answer (score 2):

Another method.

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Reference: http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero

Answer (score 0):

#### You can center a text inside a parent div using the grid layout which is widely supported now.

```
.parent-div {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I hope I helped!