# Position elements in the middle of page regardless to other elements

Tags: css, styles, styled-components

I'm new at CSS and I want to position the Inputs in the middle of the page, regardless to the button on the left, 
 + the site must be responsive.
[image]

My CSS only position them at the top center, but how can I set the `top` by my choice? (`top` won't work here)

```
display: 'flex',
justifyContent: 'center',
```

2. The `display: 'flex'` blocks the "*Email Address*" (the 3rd) input's  CSS `display: 'block'`, how can fix it to be below ?

```css
 email: {
    width: 'auto',
    display: 'block',
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  }
```

(The page is ReactJS)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Positioning <div> element at center of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862167/positioning-div-element-at-center-of-screen)

Comment: @JWGeertsma No I tried this before, its good only with one `div` element, See the post headline

Comment: you said no to the question linked by @JWGeertsma and below you say thanks to an answer that is almost the same as the one in the linked question (PS: you don't need viewport unit, use fixed position)

Comment: you said thank you to an answer that exist there so not sure what are proving with your comment. *you* are confirming that the linked question is what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could operate with viewport units and translate. For example:

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

1 vh is relative to 1% of the height of the viewport, 1 vw to the width of the viewport. So the upper left corner ist positioned in the middle of the screen. Now you translate the whole thing by 50% of it's own width and height.

Comment: Thank you ! that's helped me a lot, but I didn't get the `transform: translate`,  I read in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform but didn't understand.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/

Answer (score -1):

Or to achieve this with `display:flex` you must set the height of the html and the body to 100%.

```
html, 
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: My app is with ReactJS so I don't use `body`