# css centering with position

Tags: positioning, center, css

I have an example of absolute positioned div which is centered in the page:

**HTML**

```
<div id="test1"><img src="http://www.interactivepixel.net/images/i01.jpg" width="500" height="333"/></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test1{
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;    
   left:50%;
   width:500px;
   height:333px;
   margin-top:-166px;
   margin-left:-250px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ktFuN/

This works well until I shrink browser window so much that I get scrollbars and then even with the use of scrollbar I am loosing left and top side of the image, I cannot scroll all the way left and top of the image, like the centering doesn't work any more.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

when you reduce your window size, only the body size gets reduced, not that of the image or the explicitly sized `div#test1`. lets say the `body` size becomes `450x300 (width x height)`, ie less than the div size `500 x 333`.

Apply the CSS top and left rules to the div

left of your div calculates to `(50% of 450) = 225`
top of your div calculates to `(50% of 300) = 150`

So your div now starts from point `(225, 150) ie (left, top)`

Now apply CSS negative margins to your div
ie -250 to left and -166 to top

ie you div's position now becomes `(225-250, 150-166) ie (-25, -16) absolute position`.

Which means whenever you reduce you window size to be lesser than your absolutely positioned div size, some parts of your div would not be viewable, since `body` starts at (0, 0)

And since you've given that div negative margin for top and left, read this to understand how the div went out of view: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

You could check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page) thread for some generic css based solutions for centering an element.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. So in order to achieve what I want I would need to use jquery and write something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ktFuN/5/   Is there a way to write this just using css (no javascript or jquery)?

Comment: are you looking for a generic solution to center any image to the center of a page ? or is it just this page, with div dimensions 500 x 333 ?

Comment: Yes, for some kind of 'generic' element (not necessarily image) to be always centered, even in the window is resized.

Comment: i didn't like the negative margin, in the first place. so i used a solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page. don't know if this would serve your purpose. i've taken out the `position:absolute` as well. chk it out http://jsfiddle.net/ktFuN/6/.