# CSS - Div object centering?

Tags: css, html

I'd simply like to center a DIV object to the browser screen.

It should be something like that I think..

```
<div id="root">
    <div id="centeredElement"></div>
</div>

div#root {
    width:100%; 
}
div#centeredElement {
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    align:center;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align a <div> to the middle of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

`text-align:center`  **or** `margin:0 auto;`

as like this

```
div#centeredElement{
text-align:center;
}
```

**or**

```
div#centeredElement{
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have several options to center a div, image or other object:

1) everything inside div

```
<div align="center"> blabla </div>
```

2) for images or frames

```
<img style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" align="center" src="xx.jpg" />
```

3) another:

```
<div style="width:80%;margin-left:10%;"> blabla </div>
```

Comment: The <center> tag is deprecated as of HTML5

Answer (score 1):

Change

> align:center

to

> margin: 0px auto;