# Position header div in the centre of the screen at the top

Tags: html, css

Could anyone tell me how i would get this div to be centred at the top of the screen, with equal distances from the bounds of the page on both the left and the right.

```
position:relative;
width:800px;
height:70px;
background-color:#0CF;
left: 15%;
```

Thanks!

Comment: what div? where is the html?

Comment: You would use margin:0 auto;

Comment: A quick search finds this question a million times.  possible duplicate of [How to align a <div> to the middle of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page)

Answer (score 2):

By specifying automatic margins for left and right edges:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

This forces the browser to equalize them within the parent, which has full browser width, so it's centered since you have explicitly set the `width`.

[Sample implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/McuGU/).

Comment: All browsers since and including IE6, so doesn't really matter.

Comment: Ah i see, yes considering ie6 has been dead for some time I shouldn't worry too much about it xD. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on the parent element, and why you have it as position:relative;, but generally to center a block level element with a set width, within it's parent, you can just use:

```
margin:0 auto
```

Comment: The number `0` has no dimensions at all, so no need to specify whether it's pixels, bananas or airplanes. Common practice is to just `0` in CSS  :)

Comment: Good point, force of habit with typing, would save a couple of KB, will remove.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a width set, you should use

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9CAL3/14/) :

**HTML :**

```
<div>This is some DIV</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
div {
    width : 50%;
    margin : auto;
    border : 1px solid black; // To see that it is centered
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when doing this you want to do something like below.  It will stay withing the bounds of it's parent element and wherever you put it on the page but will place it in the middle.

If you want to put it in the code:
    style="
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;"

Otherwise just add that to your css for the div.

using this method will not set your upper and lower margin to auto.

Answer (score 0):

use margin: 0 auto;

0 - stands for 0px top and bottom sides of the page
auto - means it'll adjust itself according to the available window size and can make it center.