# how to place dropdown menu in the center of page

Tags: html

i am working on the drop down menu bar i need to place it in the center of webpage.i am calling the same div in every page of the web.

```
<head>
```

CSS

```
<style>
/*---- CROSS BROWSER DROPDOWN MENU ----*/
ul#nav {margin: 0 0 0 200px;}
ul.drop a { display:block; color: #fff; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none;}
ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #fff; background: #555; color: #fff;}
ul.drop { position: relative; z-index: 597; float: left; }
ul.drop li { float: left; line-height: 1.3em; vertical-align: middle; zoom: 1; padding: 5px 10px; }
ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover { position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default; background: #1e7c9a; }
ul.drop ul { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598; width: 195px; background: #555; border: 1px solid #fff; }
ul.drop ul li { float: none; }
ul.drop ul ul { top: -2px; left: 100%; }
ul.drop li:hover > ul { visibility: visible }
.style1 {
 font-family: calibri;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
ul.drop {
    float:left;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 597;
  }
</style>


</head>
```

HTML

```
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<ul id="nav" class="drop">

<!--<ul id="nav" class="drop">-->
  <li><span class="style1">EMS Computation</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="style1"><a href="tu.php">Optimization Through DEA</a></li></span>
      <li><span class="style1"><a href="tu.php">Optimization Through GA</a></li></span>
    </ul>
     <li><span class="style1"><a href="solar.php">Solar Panels</a></li></span>
  <li><span class="style1">Run Expert System</a>  </span>
  <ul>
      <li><span class="style1"><a href="">Run The System</a></li></span>
      <li><span class="style1"><a href="#">View The Result Of Expert System</a></li></span>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="tarrifrate.php"><span class="style1">Tarrif rate</a>  </li></span>

  <li><span class="style1">Customer Records</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="style1"><a href="">Status of Billing Of Customer </a></li></span>
         <li><span class="style1"><a href="">Delete Records </a></li></span>
         <li><span class="style1"><a href="">View Comments</a></li></span>
    </ul>
  </li>



  <li><span class="style1">Site</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="style1"><a href="#">Update</a></li></span>
      <li><span class="style1"><a href="#">View</a></li></span>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i will algin it in the center of the page...any way how to do this

Comment: you can center horizontaly using `margin: 0 auto 0 auto;` centering vertically must be done with jquery or javascript.

Comment: @joelharkes why not just `margin: 0 auto` ? :P

Comment: What happened? Did any of the solutions work for you?

Answer (score 5):

hey buddy you can do it this way

```
<div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
    centered content
</div>
```

[REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page)

One more thing, before posting on SO, searching for a relevant question, it will save lot of your valuable time .

Happy Coding :)

Comment: do you want to align the div horizontally or vertically ? the above code can align it horizontally.

Comment: horizontally in the center of every web page

Comment: @ashy1234:can u create a fiddle for your scenario, i`ll check it out

Comment: @ashy1234: you can edit the above fiddle itself, with your data.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you going through this website: http://css-tricks.com/

It tells about tricks you can do with CSS.

Well, now your answer, Try using `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updtaed **[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pT6JP/6/)**

```
ul#nav {/* margin: 0 0 0 200px;*/text-align: center;}
ul.drop { position: relative; z-index: 597; /*float: left; */}
ul.drop {
  /*float:left;*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
 }
ul.drop li { *float: left; line-height: 1.3em; vertical-align: middle; zoom: 1; padding: 5px 10px; display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/6jbQ9/2/)

You can achieve this with dreamweiver's solution in HTML or with these two below.
You will need to remove or comment out your `float: left` alignments.

Override your `ul#nav` CSS with this:

```
ul#nav {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 60%;
}
```

or this:

```
ul#nav {
    margin:auto;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
the following css can useful for you.
<div >yyyyyyyyyy</div>
div{
    margin-left:45%;
    margin-top:35%;
}
```