# Centering an element inside of a DIV using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a periodic table, and although I got the mass and the number to be placed where I want them to, the element symbol just won't budge. I tried everything: converting it from `<p>` to `<span>` to `<div>`, using `display: block` and setting `margin: 0 auto`, using `text-align: center`, but it still won't budge.

Here's the HTML:

```
        <div id = "a1" class="element alkalimetal">
            <p>
                <span id = "anumber">118</span>
                <span id = "amass">9.008</span>
            </p>
            <br>
            <div id = "symbol">H</div>
        </div>
        <div id = "a2" class = "element noblegas">

        </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#anumber{
    font-family:Arvo;
    top: 0.1em;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:super;
    font-size:1.5em;
    float:left;
    padding-left:0.2em;
}

#symbol{
    width: 5em;
    font-family: AvenirCondensed;
    font-size: 5em;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#amass{
    font-family:AvenirNext;
    top: 0.1em;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:super;
    font-size:1.5em;
    float:right;
    padding-right:0.2em
}
.element{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 8em;
    width: 8em;
    float: left;
}
```

P.S.: This table is designed for mobile so I want to avoid using `position:absolute` or fixed margin widths.

Comment: Why is the width set to 5em??

Comment: I was just trying out different things, but none of it worked. Changing the width was one of those things. At this point, I am very close to just creating an invisible div on top and centering each symbol within the invisible div.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align a <div> to the middle of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page)

Comment: @Cody Guldner I already read that thread, none of those solutions applied. P.S. I fixed the problem. Here is the fixed code for readers that have a problem with margin: 0 auto not working in the future. The key #1 was to set the inner div to float:none because it inherited this property from .element. Key #2 was to set the inner div's width to width:inherit. Code snippet attached `.symbol{
    max-height: 8em;
    width: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: AvenirCondensed;
    font-size: 4.5em;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution for readers that have a problem with margin: 0 auto not working like I did, or with a similar code. Key #1 was to set the inner div to float:none because it inherited this property from .element. Key #2 was to set the inner div's width to width:inherit so that text-align: center would position the text properly. Code snippet attached

```
.symbol{ max-height: 8em;
    width: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: AvenirCondensed;
    font-size: 4.5em;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/jAE7y/

```
#symbol{
    width: 5em;
    font-family: AvenirCondensed;
    font-size: 5em;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:center;
}
```

Here is an updated Fiddle with multiple elements http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/jAE7y/1/

Updated with alignment and fixed classes http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/jAE7y/3/

Comment: Yes, this is similar! The only improvement I can suggest would be to make the single-character elements more centered. This approach works fine with elements with two characters, but not one or three characters.

Comment: Cool. I added a Fiddle above, link here too http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/jAE7y/3/ now you can adjust the `padding-top` on the `.element` to adjust the centerness

Comment: thanks for the help! I found the bug that prevented me from centering properly in case you were curious. I commented on my post above

Answer (score 0):

Change your `#symbol` rule to the following:

```
#symbol{
    /* width: 5em; REMOVE THIS */
    font-family: AvenirCondensed;
    font-size: 5em;
    text-align:center;
    /* margin: 0 auto; REMOVE THIS */
}
```

Your width was causing the symbol to spill over the div it was sitting in, breaking the flow. The `margin: 0 auto` was no longer needed after that.

Also, as a side note, you should be using more Classes instead of ID's. ID's are intended for elements that are only used once per page. You can easily set `#symbol` to a class `.symbol` as well as `.amass` and `anumber`. This will allow you to set the CSS rules once and use them for each element in the table.

Comment: I tried this, but the symbol still didn't center. I think you are right about spilling over, because when I try to float the element to the right, it completely changes rows!