# Why display: table doesn't center the div?

Tags: html, css

```css
.headers
{
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table;
}
.logo
{
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid #00ff00;
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
}
.slogan
{
    float: right;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="headers">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="slogan">IIN</div>
</div>
```

How do i center my div[slogan] without using negative margin/top 50%?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: Tried with my css. Nothing suits

Comment: `float: right` made the div text to float at the top right.. Add `line-height: 35px;` to your CSS `.slogan`

Comment: @Pugazh I understand that problem. But not the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need `float`s when using `display: table/table-cell` ... this should center the `.slogan` div using the `table-cell` layout.

```css
.headers
{
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table;
}
.logo
{
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid #00ff00;
    /*float: left; NOT THIS */
    width: 30px;
    display: table-cell; /* THIS */
}
.slogan
{
    /*float: right; NOT THIS */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right; /* THIS */
}
```

```html
<div class="headers">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="slogan">IIN</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it aligned vertically at right. Not horizontally

Comment: Yes thanks. Should i set width to restrict it to only content's width?

Comment: @GopsAB shouldn't need to...you can set the width of the `.headers` div and `.slogan` will auto size (`.headers` width minus `.logo` width)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to middle slogan vertically then please check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/e6byt6zt/

**CSS**

```
.headers
{
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.logo
{
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid #00ff00;
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
}
.slogan
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Yes It does. Please use [ctrl+M] here after instead fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

change your slogan class with this

```
.slogan {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'margin: 0 auto ;' on the . If you want to align text inside the div you can just use 'text-align: center ;'.

Check this post [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page)

Comment: well this works if you add to your fiddle: `width: 100%;` to slogan.

Comment: Yes @DomlThe-Bread. Atanas please use demos to demonstrate your solution