# How to center grid of 4 divs?

Tags: html, css, grid, alignment

I have 4 divs but want to center them (horizontally and vertically).

Not much to say here, apparently this is quite easy but I am new to CSS and don't really know what I'm doing.
Code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <style>
 body {
 }
 div {
  background-color:#308DD4;
  opacity:0.8;
  color:white;
  width:200px; /* Change to 200 ish */
  height:auto;
  line-height:150px;
  margin:5px;
  font-size:36pt;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
 }
 a {
  display:none;
  line-height:35pt;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:20pt;
 }
 div:hover a {
  display:block;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  Test 1
  <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
  <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
  <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
 </div>
 <div style="background-color:#ff34b3">
  Test 2
  <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
  <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both;background-color:#9344bb">
  Test 3
  <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
  <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
 </div>
 <div style="background-color:#8dd430">
  Test 4
  <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
  <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
  <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ALSO BY THE WAY:

Does anyone know how to do [this](http://boards.4chan.org/g/thread/49668632)? I am trying to copy it as much as I can, but again I don't really know what I'm doing...

Thanks,
Itechmatrix

Comment: Put them all in a wrapping div and center **that** using : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-horizontally-width-of-the-page?rq=1

Comment: But the problem is that it is no easy way of centering content on a site vertically.

Comment: i tried that Paulie_D but he has to put different class on 4 div as he applied css on div which will apply..means total changes in code.

Comment: Then perhaps we need a better representation of your ***actual*** code. If your actual structure restricts some answers then you're wasting our time if  the answer can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your point then go with this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
    body {
    }
    .inner {
        background-color:#308DD4;
        opacity:0.8;
        color:white;
        width:24%; /* Change to 200 ish */
        height:auto;
        line-height:150px;
        margin:5px;
        font-size:36pt;
        font-family:sans-serif;
        text-align:center;
        float:left;
    }
    a {
        display:none;
        line-height:35pt;
        color:white;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-size:20pt;
    }
    .inner:hover a {
        display:block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:80%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
        <div class="inner">
            Test 1
            <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
            <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
            <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:#ff34b3" class="inner">
            Test 2
            <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
            <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:#9344bb" class="inner">
            Test 3
            <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
            <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:#8dd430" class="inner">
            Test 4
            <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
            <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
            <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

by this your div will be in center..please check and let me know if you still face any issue..ty

Comment: Hey, Sorry fell asleep. Your code seemed to not print out my expected result - to be clear i would like to retain the solid structure of 4 divs - without changing margin between them - but place all 4 divs to the horizontal/vertical centre of the page.

Comment: ohh so you want 2 div in top 2 bottom like in your example but that 4 div should be in middle of scrren from top and from right? like in center in screen?