# Centering a div element within another div element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I tried centering a div within another div. I saw Manoj Kumar's response to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-horizontally-width-of-the-page). But it's not working.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="contAin">
        <div class="tile">Some Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.tile {
  margin-bottom: 30px;  
  width: 80%;
}

.contAin {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

The inner div is just aligning itself to the left.

Comment: Try 
 margin:auto;
  or
text-align:center;
in main div

Comment: @PraveenKumar yea, I did, it worked.

Comment: @PraveenKumar absolutely

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `display: flex` and instead use this CSS rule for `.tile`:

```
.tile {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.tile {
  margin: 0 auto 30px;  
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contAin">
    <div class="tile">Some Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` to the same css class and check.

So, the CSS becomes:

```
.tile {
  margin-bottom: 30px;  
  width: 80%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in jsfiddle, and that's working
http://jsfiddle.net/say2vnxb/

```
.tile {
  margin-bottom: 30px;  
  width: 80%;
  background: yellow;
}

.contAin {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

What browser do you use?

Comment: chrome..and I know it's updated, I'm using bootstrap, do you think that might have something to do with it?

Comment: Yes, did you watch it in chrome inspector? Do you have link to website?

Comment: I used bootstrap, and everything is wrapped in a bootstrap column, did that affect it?

Comment: Yeah, it could rewrite some default css styles

Answer (score 0):

try this in CSS code:

```
.tile  {margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;}
```

Comment: This will not work! You cannot use `text-align: center;` for block level element. Would you like to update your answer?