# How to position a div to the center?

Tags: html, css

I am building a two column layout and I want to keep the total column inside a wrapper in the center of the screen even if it's resized. I have tried floating some CSS divs but not helping.

This is my layout:

```
<div class="wrapper"><div class="leftCol">Left</div><div class="rightCol">Right</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{ width:720px; text-align:centre;} 
.leftCol{ width:200px; float:left;} 
.rightCol{ width:510px; float:right;}
```

Comment: I believe your answer is here sir. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-horizontally-width-of-the-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is set the wrapper as such

CSS:

```
.wrapper { width:720px; margin:0px auto;}
```

Furthermore I would recommend using a bit more responsive CSS with percentage to fit with the width as well, so that it doesn't look really tiny on larger screens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Works fine for me!

Comment: Edited the answer now Roko C. Buljan

Answer (score 0):

You can try the margin trick here on the wrapper class.

```
.wrapper{ width:720px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Float** removes your children DIV elements from a static **document flow**.
DIV elements being `block-level` elements, unless set as `inline` or `inline-block` will not in any case apply to the parent's `text-align` property.

You have more possibilities, the most common are:

```
.wrapper{
    width: 720;
    margin: 0 auto; /* keeps me centered */
    overflow: auto; /* to contain floated child elements.
                    Or use a .clearfix  http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
}
```

or using `text-align: center;`

```
.wrapper{
    width: 720;
    margin: 0 auto; /* keeps me centered (use anyways) */
    text-align: center; /* my children are not block-level elements */
}
.leftCol{
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    /* text-align: left; probably you might want to reset text alignment */
} 
.rightCol{
    display: inline-block;
    width:510px;
}
```

I would **discourage** you from using (in 2016.+) **fixed widths**. Use another more responsive unit like `%` or `vw`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below css

```
.wrapper{ width:720px; text-align:centre; margin: 0 auto;} 
.leftCol{ width: 30%;  margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;} 
.rightCol{ width: 70%; margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: I didn't want percentages tho. All my attributes are in px, the combo will screw my layout up.

Comment: you can change it to px