# How to center a div (Also why i should not use <center>)?

Tags: css, html

I got 2 questions. 1st one is, how to center a div in HTML5. And why i should not use `<center>`? It still works

this is my code

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.mathijsc.net/id/' . $row['Id'] . '" data-layout="button_count" data-mobile-iframe="true" data-size="large" style="margin:0px;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -0%);">
    <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse" target="_blank">Share</a>
</div>
```

Comment: by applying css **margin:0 auto;** to the div

Comment: I the div has a fixed width you can use `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-horizontally-width-of-the-page

Comment: `<center>` tag explanation is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1798817/5743988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontal and vertical:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Horizontal:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

`<center></center>` works, but its ugly, outdated way.

Comment: Hey, i only want to center it from left to right, not to top to bottom. Which all things i should add?

Comment: just `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: eventually: `position: absolute; left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);`

Comment: not working http://kchere5.16mb.com

Comment: oh let me try the 3rd comment one

Comment: Which element are you trying to center?

Comment: I believe the horizontal and vertical example needs a few more properties and explination. Same with the horizontal example. You will need to add positioning values on multiple elements for the first example and the second example requires a width to be set to work.

Comment: @KCUploads Apply `text-align: center` to either the `div` or the `a`

Comment: Bro, how to do it with position as relative?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need something like this:

```html
<div class="content">
  <div style="border: 1px solid #000; margin:0 auto; width: 500px;" class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.mathijsc.net/id/' . $row['Id'] . '" data-layout="button_count" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should use `margin: 0 auto;`