# How to center cards in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 alpha 3.
I want to center the card horizontally in the middle across the page.

`Preview / link:` http://codepen.io/vaibhavsingh97/full/VjRAXW

I have tried all the different options listed on the bootstrap 4 example page for cards.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align a <div> to the middle (horizontally/width) of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-horizontally-width-of-the-page)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Add the css for .card

```
.card {
        margin: 0 auto; /* Added */
        float: none; /* Added */
        margin-bottom: 10px; /* Added */
}
```

here is the [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjNmNY)

**UPDATE:**
You can use the class `.mx-auto` available in bootstrap 4  to center cards.

Comment: In bootstrap 4, to center a card in a grid col, use <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center"><div class="card"></card></div>.

Comment: Applying to global is bad practice, see @ZimSystem for the correct way.

Comment: This is more of a CSS solution than a Bootstrap solution. Answer below makes more sense.

Comment: .mx-auto did the work, thanks!

Comment: BTW: if you need to center a div horizontally AND vertically, you can use `m-auto` (without the x).

Comment: my card flies off the screen when I do this.

Answer (score 126):

**Update 2019**

There is no need for extra CSS, and there are **multiple centering** methods in Bootstrap 4:

- `text-center` for center `display:inline` elements
- `mx-auto` for centering `display:block` elements inside `display:flex` (d-flex)
- `offset-*` or `mx-auto` can be used to center grid columns
- or `justify-content-center` on `row` to center grid columns

`mx-auto` (auto x-axis margins) will center inside `display:flex` elements that have a defined width, (%, vw, px, etc..). Flexbox is used by default on grid columns, so there are also [various centering methods](https://www.codeply.com/go/SOSvvKpLOc).

In your case, you can simply `mx-auto` to the cards.

Comment: I used this with the img in a card, but I had to remove card-img-top.

Comment: To align one card in center inside card deck, replace the deck for row and uses the 4th answer of this answer. btw, thanks!

Answer (score 28):

Put the elements which you want to shift to the centre within this div tag.

```
<div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

wrap all cards in a bootstrap row

```
<div class="row justify-content-center"> your cards loop </div>
```

Comment: This will center cards but not the content inside, so then include `text-center` within the card body element as well to center content `<div class="card-body text-center">`

Answer (score 6):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center vh-100">
        <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
            <div class="card shadow border">
                <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                        the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

there is no need for any internal external CSS to center the card if you have used booststrap.

Additionally, Bootstrap also includes an .mx-auto class for horizontally centering fixed-width block level content—that is, content that has display: block and a width set—by setting the horizontal margins to auto.

just use

```
      mx-auto    // place this code in your main card div
```

Answer (score 1):

### You can also use Bootstrap 4 flex classes

Like: `.align-item-center` and `.justify-content-center`

> We can use these classes identically for all device view.

Like: `.align-item-sm-center, .align-item-md-center, .justify-content-xl-center, .justify-content-lg-center, .justify-content-xs-center`

> .text-center class is used to align text in center.

Answer (score 1):

i basically suggest equal gap on right and left, and setting width to auto. Here like:

```
.bmi {         /*my additional class name -for card*/
    margin-left: 18%;      
    margin-right: 18%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

one way you can center your card is by creating three divs the first and the last with equal col-val like this.

```
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Tenetur aut officia ducimus provident facilis nam doloremque porro autem corporis.</p>
         </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```