# How to get bootstrap card to stay in the middle of the screen in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, web

I tried to get my card to stay in the middle of the screen however its not working. I used align-items and justify-content.
I have looked on different sites.

//Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="card cardalign w-50">
          <div className="card-body">
          <img className="logo" src="https://cdn.macrumors.com/article-new/2018/05/apple-music-note-800x420.jpg"/>
                <h1 className="signintext">MusicFlo Signin</h1>
                <form className="logininputs">
                <input className="emailinput" placeholder="Email"/>
                <input className="passwordinput" placeholder="Password"/>
                <button className="btn btn-primary btn-md m-2">Log In</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

And the css below

```
//App.css

.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

.logo {
  height:120px;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 150px
}

.signintext {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-style: italic
}

.logininputs {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center
}

.emailinput {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 5vh;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 2px indigo
}

.passwordinput {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 5vh;
  border: solid 2px indigo
}

.card {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 5px solid black

}
@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

I looked through the reactjs documentary. It still doesnt show in center. Please see picture. Thank you

[image]

Any info would be great

Comment: It doesnt show the whitespace that exists when i upload the photo. But basically, its on the upperleft corner of my screen

Comment: Possible duplicate  of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031224/how-to-center-cards-in-bootstrap-4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center cards in bootstrap 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031224/how-to-center-cards-in-bootstrap-4)

Answer (score 9):

add this to App css class

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

[Center div](https://codepen.io/dave-keane/pen/ZPmjjb)

Comment: or     -     margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 3):

These guys:

```
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

only work when set in conjunction with `display: flex`.

Additionally, they only work on the ***children*** of the flex container, so I don't think it would work to make card the flex container (assumming it is `card` that needs to be centred). So it is the **parent** of `card` which should have these settings:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%; // make sure the parent is full screen 
height: 100%; // so that the content will center correctly
```