# How do I center a div in the middle of the page, even if I change the window size?

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment, centering

I tried all the solutions on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-horizontally-width-of-the-page), but none of them worked. I want to center this horizontally and vertically, regardless of the window size.

Note: I have my `container` div just the way I want it. It wraps around several other divs. If I adapt the changes suggested by [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally), my container div gets messed up. I'm not trying have this be responsive. It's a fixed size (think an image), and I just want it to always be in the center of the window, regardless of window size.

Here's what I have:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  /* changed to auto, didn't make a difference*/
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
}
.light {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  border-width: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container" onclick="changeColor()">
    <div id="green" class="light"></div>
    <div id="yellow" class="light"></div>
    <div id="red" class="light"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Comment: It's rather simple if you put a `height` on `#container`, although I know that it might not be preferable.

Comment: @the12 tried those too.

Comment: Use Flexbox. It works everywhere.

Comment: @atilkan I'm not trying to have it be responsive or "flex". I just want it to stay smack dab in the middle.

Comment: try setting the `margin-left` and `margin-right` of your `div` container to `auto`

Comment: or just `margin:auto` will do

Comment: @AlanH then you ask duplicate. search google before asking at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it is not working for you as `container` is absolute and hence the `body` has zero height.

1. Add `height: 100%` to `html` and `body` first.
2. Use centering method for `absolute`ly positioned element using `transform` to `container`:

   ```
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   ```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.light {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  border-width: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container" onclick="changeColor()">
    <div id="green" class="light"></div>
    <div id="yellow" class="light"></div>
    <div id="red" class="light"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to add height to the html and body? Is this a hack?

Comment: if the `body` or any container has zero height, you have nothing to center with respect to. As your `container` is absolute, it is giving zero height to the `body`

Comment: but you can see that if you remove the height also this works!

Comment: and what about transform? Is that how people usually center things or also a hack?

Comment: this is one of the standard methods to center an absolutely / fixed positioned item in the screen...

Comment: could you please upvote if this answer helped you? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with Flexbox (I realize that in a comment you said you didn't need this 'responsive' or 'flex'). Flexbox will get this "smack-dab in the middle". The element that needs to be centered needs to have a parent element that takes the following css:

```
.whatever-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

With your example I've wrapped it in a `div` with a class of `light-wrap`. I also gave `body` and `html` 100% height so that `.light-wrap` could use a percentage value for height. If you Run Code Snippet below, make sure to try it on full screen for the full effect.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body, html {
  height:100%;
}

.light-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%; /* height is just to demonstrate  */
  background:#eee;
}

#container {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.light {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  border-width: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="light-wrap">
  <div id="container" onclick="changeColor()">

    <div id="green" class="light"></div>
    <div id="yellow" class="light"></div>
    <div id="red" class="light"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="shell">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="red">Red</div>
    <div class="green">Green</div>
    <div class="blue">Blue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.shell {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.shell:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**See fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/wLpv9x2o/3/

Edit: this is just a quick approach, style it to your needs