# Center align a div - margin:0 auto; width:980; display:block; not working

Tags: css

I am trying to center align the content on [this page](http://info.demacmedia.com/b2b-ecommerce-resolving-channel-conflict), on the class 'page-width' using this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-horizontally-width-of-the-page).

HTML:

```
<body class="full-width-template   hs-content-id-3571288255 hs-landing-page hs-page hs-content-path-b2b-ecommerce-resolving-channel-conflict hs-content-name-resolving-b2b-channel-conflict-ebook  " style="" cz-shortcut-listen="true"><div id="site-wrapper">
    <div class="header-container-wrapper">
    <div class="header-container container-fluid">

<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-1 ">
<div class="row-fluid ">
<div class="span12 widget-span widget-type-cell " style="" data-widget-type="cell" data-x="0" data-w="12">

<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-2 ">
<div class="row-fluid ">
<div class="span12 widget-span widget-type-raw_html " style="" data-widget-type="raw_html" data-x="0" data-w="12">
<div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
<span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_14770783755127411" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_raw_html" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="raw_html"><a href="http://www.demacmedia.com"><img src="http://info.demacmedia.com/hubfs/images2016/Demac-Wordmark-TealWhite.png?t=1477081795825" alt="Demac Media" style="width:149px;"></a></span>
</div><!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div><!--end widget-span -->
</div><!--end row-->
</div><!--end row-wrapper -->

</div><!--end widget-span -->
</div><!--end row-->
</div><!--end row-wrapper -->

    </div><!--end header -->
</div><!--end header wrapper -->

<div class="body-container-wrapper">
    <div class="body-container container-fluid">

<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-1 ">
<div class="row-fluid ">
<div class="span12 widget-span widget-type-cell page-width" style="margin:0 auto;width:940px;" data-widget-type="cell" data-x="0" data-w="12">

<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-2 ">
<div class="row-fluid ">
<div class="span12 widget-span widget-type-rich_text " style="" data-widget-type="rich_text" data-x="0" data-w="12">
<div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
<span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_14773109737852813" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_rich_text" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="rich_text"><div style="margin: 0 auto;">&nbsp;</div></span>
</div><!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div><!--end widget-span -->
</div><!--end row-->
</div><!--end row-wrapper -->

<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-3 ">
<div class="row-fluid ">
<div class="span12 widget-span widget-type-section_header page-width" style="" data-widget-type="section_header" data-x="0" data-w="12">
<div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
<span id="hs_cos_wrapper_section_header" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_section_header" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="section_header"><div class="page-header section-header"><h1>Resolving Channel Conflict</h1></div></span></div><!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div><!--end widget-span -->
</div><!--end row-->
</div><!--end row-wrapper -->

<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-4 ">
<div class="row-fluid ">
<div class="span12 widget-span widget-type-rich_text page-width" style="" data-widget-type="rich_text" data-x="0" data-w="12">
<div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
<span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_1402007561763651" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_rich_text" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="rich_text"><h2><img src="http://info.demacmedia.com/hubfs/eBookResolvingB2BChannelConflict_copy.jpg?t=1477081795825" alt="eBookResolvingB2BChannelConflict_copy"></h2></span>
</div><!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div><!--end widget-span -->
</div><!--end row-->
</div><!--end row-wrapper -->

<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-5 ">
<div class="row-fluid ">
<div class="span12 widget-span widget-type-cell image-resize" style="" data-widget-type="cell" data-x="0" data-w="12">

<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-6 ">
<div class="row-fluid ">
<div class="span6 widget-span widget-type-rich_text " style="" data-widget-type="rich_text" data-x="0" data-w="6">
<div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
<span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_1390854093476429" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_rich_text" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="rich_text"><h2>The new commerce reality.</h2>
<h3>The role of eCommerce in "Business-to-business" is no longer the exception, it's the rule.</h3>
<p>With access to new and better business technology, lower barriers to entry, and changing consumer expectations we’re seeing a shift occur with new and exciting products being available to buy online. B2B buyer behaviour is changing rapidly and continues to do so. What's your strategy to adapt and serve their needs?</p>
<p>Make better B2B today and overcome your challenges by downloading your copy of our free eBook today.&nbsp;</p></span>
</div><!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div><!--end widget-span -->
<div class="span6 widget-span widget-type-form " style="" data-widget-type="form" data-x="6" data-w="6">
<div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
<span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_1390853976625824" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_form" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="form"><h3 id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_1390853976625824_title" class="hs_cos_wrapper form-title" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_field" data-hs-cos-type="text">Download Your Copy</h3>

<div id="hs_form_target_module_1390853976625824"><form novalidate="" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://forms.hubspot.com/uploads/form/v2/174347/5779487a-3982-4651-85e8-ec5a967da68a" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="hsForm_5779487a-3982-4651-85e8-ec5a967da68a_6619" method="POST" class="hs-form stacked hs-custom-form" data-form-id="5779487a-3982-4651-85e8-ec5a967da68a" data-portal-id="174347" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0"><fieldset class="form-columns-1" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0"><div class="hs_hs_persona field hs-form-field smart-field" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.1:$hs_persona"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your Persona" for="hs_persona-5779487a-3982-4651-85e8-ec5a967da68a_6619" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.1:$hs_persona.0"><span data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.1:$hs_persona.0.0">Persona</span><span class="hs-form-required" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.1:$hs_persona.0.1">*</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.1:$hs_persona.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona"><select id="hs_persona-5779487a-3982-4651-85e8-ec5a967da68a_6619" required="" class="hs-input" name="hs_persona" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0"><option value="" disabled="" selected="" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0.0">- Please Select -</option><option value="persona_5" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0.1:$persona_5">I implement code or marketing programs in a project</option><option value="persona_8" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0.1:$persona_8">I am responsible for picking the technology that will work for our business</option><option value="persona_9" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0.1:$persona_9">I allocate budget and make the financial decisions in a project</option><option value="persona_10" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0.1:$persona_10">I want to join the Demac Media team</option><option value="persona_11" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0.1:$persona_11">I want to establish a strategic alliance with Demac Media</option><option value="persona_12" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0.1:$persona_12">I am a member of the press</option></select></div></div></fieldset><fieldset class="form-columns-1" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1"><div class="hs_ecommerce_platform field hs-form-field smart-field" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your eCommerce Platform" for="ecommerce_platform-5779487a-3982-4651-85e8-ec5a967da68a_6619" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.0"><span data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.0.0">eCommerce Platform</span><span class="hs-form-required" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.0.1">*</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform"><select id="ecommerce_platform-5779487a-3982-4651-85e8-ec5a967da68a_6619" required="" class="hs-input" name="ecommerce_platform" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0"><option value="" disabled="" selected="" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.0">- Please Select -</option><option value="Magento" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$Magento">Magento</option><option value="Shopify Plus" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$Shopify Plus">Shopify Plus</option><option value="Shopify" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$Shopify">Shopify</option><option value="WebLinc" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$WebLinc">WebLinc</option><option value="Big Commerce" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$Big Commerce">Big Commerce</option><option value="Demandware" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$Demandware">Demandware</option><option value="Drupal Commerce" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$Drupal Commerce">Drupal Commerce</option><option value="Hybris" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$Hybris">Hybris</option><option value="IBM Websphere" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$IBM Websphere">IBM Websphere</option><option value="Open Cart" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$Open Cart">Open Cart</option><option value="Oracle ATG Commerce" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$Oracle ATG Commerce">Oracle ATG Commerce</option><option value="osCommerce" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$osCommerce">osCommerce</option><option value="Prestashop" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$Prestashop">Prestashop</option><option value="Volusion" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$Volusion">Volusion</option><option value="Woo Commerce" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$Woo Commerce">Woo Commerce</option><option value="xCart" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$xCart">xCart</option><option value="Zen Cart" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$Zen Cart">Zen Cart</option><option value="Other" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$Other">Other</option><option value="I don't have an eCommerce store" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$1.1:$ecommerce_platform.$ecommerce_platform.0.1:$I don't have an eCommerce store">I don't have an eCommerce store</option></select></div></div></fieldset><fieldset class="form-columns-1" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$2"><div class="hs_opt_in field hs-form-field smart-field" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$2.1:$opt_in"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your Opt-in" for="opt_in-5779487a-3982-4651-85e8-ec5a967da68a_6619" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$2.1:$opt_in.0"><span data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$2.1:$opt_in.0.0">Opt-in</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$2.1:$opt_in.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$2.1:$opt_in.$opt_in"><ul class="inputs-list multi-container" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$2.1:$opt_in.$opt_in.0"><li class="hs-form-radio" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$2.1:$opt_in.$opt_in.0.$I would like to receive insights from Demac from time to time, and may change my email preferences at any time=1"><label for="opt_in0-5779487a-3982-4651-85e8-ec5a967da68a_6619" class="hs-form-radio-display" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$2.1:$opt_in.$opt_in.0.$I would like to receive insights from Demac from time to time, and may change my email preferences at any time=1.0"><input id="opt_in0-5779487a-3982-4651-85e8-ec5a967da68a_6619" class="hs-input" type="radio" name="opt_in" value="I would like to receive insights from Demac from time to time, and may change my email preferences at any time." data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$2.1:$opt_in.$opt_in.0.$I would like to receive insights from Demac from time to time, and may change my email preferences at any time=1.0.0"><span data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$2.1:$opt_in.$opt_in.0.$I would like to receive insights from Demac from time to time, and may change my email preferences at any time=1.0.1">I would like to receive insights from Demac from time to time, and may change my email preferences at any time.</span></label></li></ul></div></div></fieldset><div class="hs_submit" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.2"><div class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.2.0"></div><div class="actions" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.2.1"><input type="submit" value="Download the eBook" class="hs-button primary large" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.2.1.0"></div></div><input name="hs_context" type="hidden" value="{&quot;rumScriptExecuteTime&quot;:1424.5400000000002,&quot;rumServiceResponseTime&quot;:1780.205,&quot;rumFormRenderTime&quot;:325.0250000000003,&quot;rumTotalRequestTime&quot;:321.7549999999999,&quot;css&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;pageUrl&quot;:&quot;http://info.demacmedia.com/b2b-ecommerce-resolving-channel-conflict&quot;,&quot;pageTitle&quot;:&quot;B2B eCommerce: Resolving Channel Conflict&quot;,&quot;isHostedOnHubspot&quot;:true,&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477311186415,&quot;userAgent&quot;:&quot;Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36&quot;,&quot;referrer&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;hutk&quot;:&quot;7b537ec0b4e8c7e5df5f329373e6a047&quot;,&quot;originalEmbedContext&quot;:{&quot;portalId&quot;:&quot;174347&quot;,&quot;formId&quot;:&quot;5779487a-3982-4651-85e8-ec5a967da68a&quot;,&quot;formInstanceId&quot;:&quot;6619&quot;,&quot;pageId&quot;:3571288255,&quot;followUpEmailId&quot;:3426872907,&quot;followUpEmailCampaignId&quot;:22668042,&quot;notificationRecipients&quot;:&quot;p2ANqtz-_9vbKt3EwJCKl21LwRSf6c9DILGukf5pRhJlzlRr9ZNlA7ybwvDSU7DpZWljWUdYXUtCdX_cxtp5m3D3O51_nq2t5GNQ5h8JJeMjIs8MkVibr1wClBl_FxIdox1MB1HjZgRDiJ&quot;,&quot;pageName&quot;:&quot;B2B eCommerce: Resolving Channel Conflict&quot;,&quot;redirectUrl&quot;:&quot;http://info.demacmedia.com/b2b-ecommerce-resolving-channel-conflict?portalId=174347&amp;hsFormKey=b84bd04c8f1000afdd28369484ce7328#module_1390853976625824&quot;,&quot;css&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;target&quot;:&quot;#hs_form_target_module_1390853976625824&quot;,&quot;contentType&quot;:&quot;landing-page&quot;,&quot;formData&quot;:{&quot;cssClass&quot;:&quot;hs-form stacked hs-custom-form&quot;}},&quot;recentFieldsCookie&quot;:{},&quot;pageId&quot;:&quot;3571288255&quot;,&quot;pageName&quot;:&quot;B2B eCommerce: Resolving Channel Conflict&quot;,&quot;boolCheckBoxFields&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;dateFields&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;redirectUrl&quot;:&quot;http://info.demacmedia.com/b2b-ecommerce-resolving-channel-conflict?portalId=174347&amp;hsFormKey=b84bd04c8f1000afdd28369484ce7328#module_1390853976625824&quot;,&quot;formInstanceId&quot;:&quot;6619&quot;,&quot;smartFields&quot;:{&quot;firstname&quot;:&quot;dfsf sf dsf sf sdf sd &quot;,&quot;lastname&quot;:&quot;sdf sdfs&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;bprice+admin@demacmedia.com&quot;,&quot;company&quot;:&quot;tgtgtdfgfdg&quot;,&quot;jobtitle&quot;:&quot;tgtgttgtgt&quot;},&quot;urlParams&quot;:{},&quot;notificationRecipients&quot;:&quot;p2ANqtz-_9vbKt3EwJCKl21LwRSf6c9DILGukf5pRhJlzlRr9ZNlA7ybwvDSU7DpZWljWUdYXUtCdX_cxtp5m3D3O51_nq2t5GNQ5h8JJeMjIs8MkVibr1wClBl_FxIdox1MB1HjZgRDiJ&quot;,&quot;formValidity&quot;:{},&quot;followUpEmailId&quot;:3426872907,&quot;followUpEmailCampaignId&quot;:22668042,&quot;correlationId&quot;:&quot;cf926406-ba90-48b6-ace5-60f4ed341ab5&quot;,&quot;disableCookieSubmission&quot;:false}" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.3"></form></div>





</span>
</div><!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div><!--end widget-span -->
</div><!--end row-->
</div><!--end row-wrapper -->

<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-7 ">
<div class="row-fluid ">
<div class="span12 widget-span widget-type-widget_container full-width" style="" data-widget-type="widget_container" data-x="0" data-w="12">
<span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_13904520441077528" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container"></span>
</div><!--end widget-span -->
</div><!--end row-->
</div><!--end row-wrapper -->

</div><!--end widget-span -->
</div><!--end row-->
</div><!--end row-wrapper -->

<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-8 ">
<div class="row-fluid ">
<div class="span12 widget-span widget-type-rich_text " style="" data-widget-type="rich_text" data-x="0" data-w="12">
<div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
<span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_14773110454353630" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_rich_text" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="rich_text"></span>
</div><!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div><!--end widget-span -->
</div><!--end row-->
</div><!--end row-wrapper -->

</div><!--end widget-span -->
</div><!--end row-->
</div><!--end row-wrapper -->

<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-9 ">
<div class="row-fluid ">
<div class="span12 widget-span widget-type-rich_text " style="" data-widget-type="rich_text" data-x="0" data-w="12">
<div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
<span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_14770601891791022" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_rich_text" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="rich_text"><footer class="site-footer text-center">
<div class="site-footer__info text-center">
<div class="page-width">
<div class="grid">
<div class="grid__item medium-up--one-quarter medium-up--text-left">© 2016 Demac Media</div>
<div class="grid__item medium-up--three-quarters medium-up--text-right">
<div class="site-footer__menu-container">
<ul id="FooterMenu" class="site-footer__menu">
<li class="menu-item "><a href="http://staging.demacmedia.com/services/">Services</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://staging.demacmedia.com/work/">Work</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://staging.demacmedia.com/partners/">Partners</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://staging.demacmedia.com/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://staging.demacmedia.com/careers/">Careers</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://staging.demacmedia.com/blog/">Blog</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://staging.demacmedia.com/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</footer></span>
</div><!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div><!--end widget-span -->
</div><!--end row-->
</div><!--end row-wrapper -->

    </div><!--end body -->
</div><!--end body wrapper -->

<div class="footer-container-wrapper">
    <div class="footer-container container-fluid">


    </div><!--end footer -->
</div><!--end footer wrapper -->




        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script charset="utf-8" src="https://js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->






<!-- Start of HubSpot Analytics Code -->




<!-- End of HubSpot Analytics Code -->










    <!-- Generated by the HubSpot Template Builder - template version 1.03 -->

<!-- end coded_template: id:968116727 path:generated_layouts/968116712.html -->
</div><div class="hs-tools-menu hs-collapsed">
    <img class="hs-sprocket" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/static/sprocket_white_80.png">
    <div class="hs-dropdown">
        <div class="hs-title">HubSpot Tools</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="https://app.hubspot.com/content/174347/edit-beta/3571288255?__hstc=73884557.7b537ec0b4e8c7e5df5f329373e6a047.1476186906536.1477078220412.1477308692970.38&amp;__hssc=73884557.18.1477308692970&amp;__hsfp=1256358867">
    Edit Page
</a></li><li><a target="_blank" href="https://app.hubspot.com/pages-beta/174347/analyze/landing/page/3571288255?__hstc=73884557.7b537ec0b4e8c7e5df5f329373e6a047.1476186906536.1477078220412.1477308692970.38&amp;__hssc=73884557.18.1477308692970&amp;__hsfp=1256358867">
    View Page Details
</a></li><li><a target="_blank" href="https://app.hubspot.com/pages-beta/174347/manage/landing?__hstc=73884557.7b537ec0b4e8c7e5df5f329373e6a047.1476186906536.1477078220412.1477308692970.38&amp;__hssc=73884557.18.1477308692970&amp;__hsfp=1256358867">
    Landing Pages
</a></li><li><a target="_blank" href="https://app.hubspot.com/content/174347/settings/url-mappings?__hstc=73884557.7b537ec0b4e8c7e5df5f329373e6a047.1476186906536.1477078220412.1477308692970.38&amp;__hssc=73884557.18.1477308692970&amp;__hsfp=1256358867">
    URL Mappings
</a></li><li><a target="_blank" href="https://app.hubspot.com/content/template-context-redirect?portalId=174347&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Finfo.demacmedia.com%2Fb2b-ecommerce-resolving-channel-conflict&amp;__hstc=73884557.7b537ec0b4e8c7e5df5f329373e6a047.1476186906536.1477078220412.1477308692970.38&amp;__hssc=73884557.18.1477308692970&amp;__hsfp=1256358867">
    Developer Info
</a></li><li><a target="_blank" href="https://app.hubspot.com/content/174347/template-builder?__hstc=73884557.7b537ec0b4e8c7e5df5f329373e6a047.1476186906536.1477078220412.1477308692970.38&amp;__hssc=73884557.18.1477308692970&amp;__hsfp=1256358867#968116712">
    Edit Layout
</a></li>
            <li class="hs-menu-hider"><a>Hide This Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><div id="tqShowIP" class="tqShowIP_right">182.176.154.42</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.page-width{
max-width:980px;
padding:0 20px;
margin:0 auto;
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Add this, it will work

```
 float: none;


     .page-width{
      max-width:980px;
      padding:0 20px;
      margin:0 auto;
      display:block;
      float: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it will taking default css property : Remove it or add css `float: none` and  `margin: 0 auto`  with important

```
.page-width {
    max-width: 980px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    float: none !important;
}
```