# CSS layout, flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The "red" div (seen in the image) is in the "head" div. I'm using flexbox to positioning simply like that:

```css
#head {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

I want to overflow the red to the gray area like in the picture. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Create a separate div for red part, and then:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-horizontally-width-of-the-page

Comment: A negative `margin-bottom` for the red div will probably do the trick. You might need to modify the `z-index` as well, so that the grey #body content does not overlap it.

Answer (score 2):

Apply one of these rules

```css
#red {
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

or

```css
#red {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
```