# How to center align two table side by side?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to center align 2 in-line tables in html.

my snippet of code:

```
<div class="sometables" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <table style="display:inline-table;float:left;width:30%;margin-right:230px;">
      <tr>               
        <th>Application<br>Processed</th>
        <th>Application<br>ID</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
      </tr>
  
      {% for processed in processed_data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{processed[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{processed[3]}}</td>
        <td>{{processed[1]}}</td> 
        <td>{{processed[2]}}</td>
      </tr>
  
      {% endfor %}   
    </table>
    <table style="display:inline-table;float:left;width:30%;">
    
      <tr>
        <th>Application<br>Flagged</th>
        <th>Application<br>ID</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
      </tr>
 
      {% for flagged in flagged_data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{flagged[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{flagged[3]}}</td>
        <td>{{flagged[1]}}</td> 
        <td>{{flagged[2]}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}   
    </table>
</div>
```

Current output is:

[image]

How can I center align the two tables together?

Research and Due Diligence:

- [W3: CSS Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)
- [HubSpot: 11 Ways to Center Div or Text in Div in CSS](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/center-div-css)
- [SO: How to align a  to the middle (horizontally/width) of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-horizontally-width-of-the-page)

Comment: Can't run this, maybe `.sometables { display: grid; place-items: center; width: 100% /* not sure */ }` works for you? And what's with the inline 'margin-right: 230px'? This messes with your Left/Right positioning...

Comment: @RenevanderLende I'm new to HTML - I wanted two tables side by side with some spacing in between... Can you give me any suggestions?!

Comment: You're obviously using some pre-processor, so I can't run your code, but the simple *rule of thumb* would be: *stretch* the parent (`.sometables`) to full width (of either `<body>` or some other parent element) and *center* its child content (your two tables). Hence my previous comment. Margins are *never* part of the total width of a child element, causing unwanted extra shifting inside a parent. For child spacing when using `display: grid` use a convenient value for `column-gap` (or shorthand `gap`) in the parent definition (e.g. `.sometables { column-gap: 2em }`). Remove the inline `margin`

Comment: @RenevanderLende I'm using Python's Flask Env. to create the website tied to a local database. Hard to reproduce MWE with so many moving parts.
Are you able to share the snippet of code? ? What would that chunk of code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per OP request for code, not checked as it cannot be executed runtime.

Remove references to inline `margin` and create a basic CSS Grid parent `.sometables`, which gets stretched to fill its parent (assumably `body`) and add some convenient spacing between the two child elements (`table`) with `column-gap` (where any preferred value will do).

*Notice* the removal of `margin` definitions...

**Update** the CSS grid needs a `grid-template-columns` definition to show the tables side-by-side instead of stacked on top of eachother. Each table gets `1fr` (one fraction) of the total space available.

Make sure to visit [Grid by Example](https://gridbyexample.com/), well worth your time.

```css
.sometables {
  /* CSS Grid settings */
  display: grid; place-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 2em;
  
  width: 100%; /* to fill full width of parent */
}
```

```html
<div class="sometables">
    <table style="display:inline-table;float:left;width:30%;">
      <tr>               
        <th>Application<br>Processed</th>
        <th>Application<br>ID</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
      </tr>
  
      {% for processed in processed_data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{processed[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{processed[3]}}</td>
        <td>{{processed[1]}}</td> 
        <td>{{processed[2]}}</td>
      </tr>
  
      {% endfor %}   
    </table>
    <table style="display:inline-table;float:left;width:30%;">
    
      <tr>
        <th>Application<br>Flagged</th>
        <th>Application<br>ID</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
      </tr>
 
      {% for flagged in flagged_data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{flagged[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{flagged[3]}}</td>
        <td>{{flagged[1]}}</td> 
        <td>{{flagged[2]}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}   
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Any pointers if I want to convert `<th>Application<br>Flagged</th>` to `<th style="width:200px">Application<br>Flagged</th>` - I can't seem force 200px on the first column...

Comment: Use `min-width` instead. You will likely get in trouble using these tables anyway as they are defined as `width 30%` but it may well be that, on browser resize, the `30%` is not wide enough to hold the summed total width of a single row. Then you will have to decide whether to scale down the entire table, or use a different approach like *flexbox* or *CSS grid*. BTW, I removed the 'Convenient...' as that won't happen because of the `width: 30%`. CSS will keep trying to fit each table in a 30% space, no matter how narrow that gets.